# Memory leak on setFrame:

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, categories, xcode-instruments

I test my `project` in `Instruments`, and last I found a `memory leak` in a `UIView`'s category: `UIView+RSAdditions`

[image: The memory leak]

The code below:

```
- (void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    self.frame = frame;  // this code cause memory leak
}
```

I also searched my `project`, and found some the same method name here:

[image: The method name is the same]

Does those same method affect the memory leak? And I am confused about the `memory leak`'s reason.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience. The instrument doesn't really tell you which line causes a leak. It just tells you that the line is included in one of the stack traces that causes the leak. It just helps you to track the leak easier because you will know how the program flows. You have to track it on your own base on the stack trace that the instrument gave you.

Here's a sample screenshot of stack trace from the instrument:

[image]

From my previous debugging, these are my mistakes that causes memory leaks under ARC

- Set a strong reference to a parent in a child object. This causes a
  retain cycle.
- Set a strong reference to a delegate in an interface.
- Forgot to release an object when you do a toll-free bridging after
  transferring ownership.
- Forgot to set a weak reference to objects you
  passed in a block.

I hope that helps

Comment: what mean of `do a toll-free bridging after transferring owenership`?

Comment: @aircraft Like for instance you are going to cast an NSArray to CFArrayRef and retain it: CFArrayRef arrayRef = (__bridge_retained) anNSArray; Now since you are retaining it. You need to release it yourself like CFRelease() or something